# Using Rails test fixture helpers in Cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I'd like to be able to use Rails' test fixture helpers in Cucumber, but the information provided on the Cucumber wiki seems... out of date at best: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Fixtures (heading: Fixture Helper Methods)

Google has been less than helpful.

Is there a good way to do this?

**Update**: Tried using ActiveRecord::TestFixtures to no avail it seems like this is the class to do the job, but can't get it mixed into the World correctly

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons there's so little information on fixtures is that most rails developers are now all using [Factory Girl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) to generate test data.

Factory Girl provides you mush more control over both the data that's generated (and when it's created), but it also allows you a lot more control of the associated model classes you inevitably will need.

Comment: That's fair, but the problem therein is when you have a large and complicated object tree. You have to find a root or you have to init and create TONS of objects and link them all together. Fixtures allow me to set up a couple of consistent scenarios and then tweak them ever so slightly.

Answer (score 0):

After an hour of brain cramming, I was able to make it work.
Replace

```
fix = Fixtures.cached_fixtures(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, table_name)[fixture_symbol.to_s]
```

with

```
fix = Fixtures.cached_fixtures(ActiveRecord::Base.connection, table_name).first.fixtures[fixture_symbol.to_s]
```

I have already updated the wiki at https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Fixtures